# TypeError: this.props.filterUser is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I got this error: TypeError: this.props.filterUser is not a function

I have encountered a problem. Suppose after login successfully, it will jump to the main page. The main page contains the sidebar, which will display on the left-hand side. In the below code, after logging in, the sidebar will contain the content of the login page. Also, the response value cannot pass to the sidebar.
What I want is that when pressing the login button, it will call the API call and get back the response value. These values will pass to filterUser in the sidebar.

In this case, seems I need to separate the handleSubmit into two parts. One is to solve with the API call. Another one is to solve with the role. but i have no idea how to separate this.

Here is the login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loginName: "",
      password: "",
      isLoggedOn: false,
      role: null,
    };
    console.log(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var response = LoginAction(this.state)    
    response.then((data) => {
      this.setState({ isLoggedOn: data.isLoggedOn })
      if(data.role) {
        this.setState({role: "Admin"});
      } else {
        this.setState({role: "General User"});
      }
      if (data.isLoggedOn) {
        console.log(this.props.filterUser)
        this.props.filterUser(this.state.role);
      }
    })
  }


  render() {

    return (
        <div className="login-form">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="input-container">
              <label>User ID</label>
              <input type="text" name="loginName" value={this.state.loginName} onChange={(e) => (this.setState({ loginName: e.target.value }))} />
            </div>
            <div className="input-container">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => (this.setState({ password: e.target.value }))} />
            </div>
            <div className="button-container"><input type="submit" value="CONNECT"></input></div>
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the role.js

```
export default withRouter(Login);
        class Role extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                role: "",
            }
            this.filterUser = this.filterUser.bind(this);
        }
        filterUser(roleValue) {
            this.setState({role: roleValue});
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Login filterUser={this.filterUser} />
                    <h5>User: {this.state.role}</h5>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default Role;
```

here is the result of props

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you log `this.props.filterUser` to check the value out

Comment: @TusharShahi I get undefined

Comment: can you log the props in Login component constructor

Comment: @KushalJain yes, I got the information(router and Prototype, etc...)

Comment: Don't you get filterUser as props in the constructor ? can you post the screenshot of it?

Comment: @KushalJain I have posted it. The state is null? will it cause the problem?

Comment: I would suggest remove this export default withRouter(Login); and just export default Login then try to use in any other components by passing different props for test purpose as well. then try to log props in the constructor